# How to remove embedded text from a gif image?

Tags: image

I have a gif button which has an embedded text called : "MA". Now i want to change the text to : "BA" . Can i do this online ? If yes, how ? Otherwise what are my options ?

Comment: Edit completely to change to BA, but the back ground color has to remain the same for the btn

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by [Adobe ImageReady](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adobe_ImageReady).

Comment: Is this an online tool ? Because i cant download from my place as my org has restrictions on downloading softwares .

Comment: No it does not help. I have used it, there is no feature to remove the already embedded text or at least i could not find one

Comment: Ok will try the Adobe image now

Comment: I am inside the adobe image page, but not finding a way to upload the image and edit it. Will be very glad if u helped out here.

Comment: I tried none of them have the feature to edit an embedded text .

Comment: i think you should replace that frame has "MA" text with an frame containing "BA" text.